# dependentObservable initialization

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

As i know dependentObservable calculating when it has been declared.
But what if some values doesnt exists yet?

for example:

```
var viewModel ={};

var dependentObservable1 = ko.dependentObservable(function(){

     return viewModel.abc;

},viewModel);

viewModel.abc = 123;
```

it's easy example but you can see case with a few dependentObservable on a picture below.

[image]

How i can resolve this issue? May be use timer or something? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNJN5/115/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a flag that you can pass when creating a dependentObservable to defer the evaluation until it is referenced by something (like a binding).

You would define your dependentObservable using an object literal like:

```
var dependentObservable1 = ko.dependentObservable({
    read: function() {
        return viewModel.abc;
    },
    deferEvaluation: true,
    owner: viewModel
});
```